# On the basis of an orthogonal complement

Tags: vector-spaces

Find a basis for the orthogonal complement of the subspace
$V \in R^4$ given by
V ={$x\in R^4 | x_1 +x_2- 2x_4 =0, x_1 -x_2 -x_3 +6x_4 =0, x_2 +x_3 -4x_4 =0$}.

I've tried rewriting as a basis of V and then row reducing. I've also tried transposing the matrix. No matter what I do, I keep getting that the zero vector is the only basis of the orthogonal complement. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: apologies for the typos. Should be ok now.

Comment: How can a matrix be a basis of a subspace of $\mathbb R^4$?

Comment: When you wrote $x_2\in R^4$, did you mean $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in\mathbb R^4$?

Comment: Apologies for the typos. Should be ok now. @JoséCarlosSantos

Answer (score 1):

Let’s rewrite the defining equations of $V$ as $$\begin{align} (1,1,0,-2)\cdot x &= 0 \\ (1,-1,-1,6)\cdot x &= 0 \\ (0,1,1,-4)\cdot x &= 0. \end{align}$$ These equations say that $V$ consists of the vectors that are orthogonal to all three of the above fixed vectors. By linearity of the dot product, any $x\in V$ is also orthogonal to any linear combination of these vectors. $V$ is therefore the orthogonal complement of the span of these vectors, hence $V^\perp = \operatorname{span}\{(1,1,0,-2),(1,-1,-1,6),(0,1,1,-4)\}.$We can see by inspection that these vectors are linearly independent, so they form a basis for $V^\perp$ as well.

In terms of the coefficient matrix of the defining system, $V$ is its null space. Recall that the *row* space of a matrix is the orthogonal complement of its null space, so the nonzero rows of the reduced coefficient matrix are a basis for $V^\perp$.

Answer (score 0):

Your space $V$ consists of the vectors $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ such that$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x_1+x_2-2x_4=0\\x_1-x_2-x_3+6x_4=0\\x_2+x_3-4x_4=0.\end{array}\right.$$But this system is equivalent to$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x_1=-7x_4\\x_2=9x_4\\x_3=-10x_4.\end{array}\right.$$So,$$V=\mathbb R(-7,9,-10,1)$$and therefore$$V^\perp=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in\mathbb R^4\mid -7x_1+9x_2-10x_3+x_4=0\}.$$